# Select elements of list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

I have a list of lists

```
list={l1,l2,l3,l4,...};
```

and two elements `e1,e2`. I want to select from lists `l1,l2,l3,...` those containing elements `e1,e2`.

I tried

```
Select[list, MemberQ[#, e1] && MemberQ[#, e2] &];
```

but it's too slow (as `list` may be quite large and I have a lot of `e1,e2` combinations).

Comment: Is `list` one dimensional or are the `l1,l2....` each lists themselves?

Comment: `l1,l2,...` are lists as well

Comment: `Cases` looks roughly twice as fast when using lists of lists of integers and `e1` `e2` also integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a mild improvement:

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {50, 5}];
e1 = 1; e2 = 2;
Cases[list, {___, e1, ___, e2, ___} | {___, e2, ___, e1, ___}] // AbsoluteTiming
Select[list, MemberQ[#, e1] && MemberQ[#, e2] &] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000227842, {{1, 2, 6, 5, 5}, {1, 9, 9, 1, 2}, {6, 1, 2, 8, 1}, {5, 
>      2, 8, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 9, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 4, 2}, {7, 7, 1, 9, 2}, {6,
>       0, 1, 2, 9}, {0, 0, 8, 2, 1}, {9, 5, 1, 2, 0}, {8, 1, 5, 2, 9}}}
>
> {0.000355521, {{1, 2, 6, 5, 5}, {1, 9, 9, 1, 2}, {6, 1, 2, 8, 1}, {5, 
>      2, 8, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 9, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 4, 2}, {7, 7, 1, 9, 2}, {6,
>       0, 1, 2, 9}, {0, 0, 8, 2, 1}, {9, 5, 1, 2, 0}, {8, 1, 5, 2, 9}}}

`Cases`, as you can see, is slightly faster. Sadly the improvement is less than a factor of two.

Here's a much faster solution:

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {50000, 5}];
e1 = 1; e2 = 2;
Pick[list, Unitize@(Count[#, e1] Count[#, e2] & /@ list), 1]
(* output omitted *)
```

Comparisons:

```
Select[list, MemberQ[#, e1] && MemberQ[#, e2] &] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Cases[list, {___, e1, ___, e2, ___} | {___, e2, ___, e1, ___}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Pick[list, Unitize@(Count[#, e1] Count[#, e2] & /@ list), 1] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 0.252361 *)

(* 0.133419 *)

(* 0.0178847 *)
```

About 15 times faster than `Select/MemberQ`.

The situation changes when I tried this with symbolic elements in the list:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
list = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}, {50000, 5}];
e1 = a; e2 = b;

Select[list, MemberQ[#, e1] && MemberQ[#, e2] &] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Cases[list, {___, e1, ___, e2, ___} | {___, e2, ___, e1, ___}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Pick[list, Unitize@(Count[#, e1] Count[#, e2] & /@ list), 1] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 0.158247 *)

(* 0.0228719 *)

(* 0.23266 *)
```

This time `Cases` is the fastest.

Comment: The method using `Pick` doesn't give the same answer as the others, see this:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RxU0ribV

Comment: You are right, thanks for the heads up. The culprit is a necessary pair of parentheses. It does not seem to affect the timing. Editing now.

Comment: @JasonB fixed. It was unitizing only the count of `e1` before, not the product of the counts. The updated `Pick` is still the fastest for integers though.

Comment: I was looking at this one too, and if you are interested in some really slow methods, try replacing the `MemberQ[#, e1] && MemberQ[#, e2] &` from OP's method with `SubsetsQ[#,{e1,e2}]&` or `ContainsAll[#,{e1,e2}]&` - simply atrocious results

Comment: Oh yeah, this new-found `Contains`-whatever functionality is terrible. I went through those too along the way. I do wonder, why patterns are so fast with symbols though and why `Pick` suffers a slowdown

Comment: Yes, it runs faster, thank you!