# Delete row which contains specifc elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Let's assume we have a matrix:

$m=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
g & h & i\\
d & e & f
\end{array}\right]$

and we want to delete the row witch contains the follwing elements:

$identifyElem=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
h & i\end{array}\right]$

The output should be:

$m=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f
\end{array}\right]$

Comment: `DeleteCases[m, {___, i | h, ___}]` works if it's either h or i. `DeleteCases[m, {___, h, ___, i, ___}]` if it's h and i.

Comment: @kale Thanks, I will try that. :)

Comment: @kale Works !! Thank you! :D

Comment: @ kale: post this as an answer please.

Comment: [Select elements of list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97082/5478) but `Cases -> DeleteCases` etc.